# How to pass the value of a form to another form?

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a task in which I need to pass the value of a form in a page to another one. I am using `POST` method to do this, but it is not working. I would really appreciate some help.

This is the code I am using:

**First Form** (`form2.php`)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>FORM</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="form3.php" method="post">
            Name:<input type="text" name="name">
            Address:<input type="text" name="address">
            <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Second Form** (`form3.php`)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>MY HOMEPAGE</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php
        $x=$_POST['name'];
        $y=$_POST['address'];

    echo $x;
    echo $y;

    ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: your forms looks very fine. what is the problem you get.

Comment: your question is quite unclear. please explain in details and also share your second form code

Comment: Looks like it should work, so whats the problem?

Comment: Check you  your form name **Form3.php**  and your  <form action="**form3.php**" method="post">  not the same

Answer (score 0):

At first glance, your code seems just fine. There are a few *minor* things you have missed, though none of them should normally prevent you from getting the output. But just to be sure, I have tidied up the code and added a test for each `POST` variable.

Try the following and see if it works.

**First Form** (`form2.php`)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>FORM</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="form3.php" method="POST">
            Name:<input type="text" name="name" />
            Address:<input type="text" name="address" />
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Second Form** (`form3.php`)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>MY HOMEPAGE</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php
        if(isset($_POST['submit']))
        {
            if(isset($_POST['name']))
            {               
                $x=$_POST['name'];
            }
            if(isset($_POST['address']))
            {               
                $y=$_POST['address'];
            }
        }
        echo $x;
        echo $y;
    ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

> This is what I added to your code:
>
> 1. Closed the open `input` tags in `form2.php`.
> 2. Added `isset` to check if the `POST` data is being received in the `form3.php` file.
> 3. Added `isset` to all the variables (`name` and `address` in this case) to check if they are being received.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using linux environment, the form action (*`form3.php`*) and file name (*`Form3.php`*)  are not same. In linux environment these are **case sensitive**. Please make action uri & file name in same case.