# Pass form results to another form into a form value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, forms

I have two forms on a page the "top form" searches for movies and I'm trying to get the data found from the top form and pass it as a value to the bottom form so it can get entered into a database.

I am unable to do this but, I can get the results to be displayed on the page. Here is my code:

**TOP FORM DATA**

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<?php
$squery="";
if(isset($_GET["squery"]))
{
$squery=$_GET["squery"];
}
?>
<div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2">
<form action="#" method="GET" class="form-horizontal">
<div class="form-group">
        <label for="newMovieName" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Search what movie?</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9"> <input type="text" name="squery" class="form-control"><br />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-success"></div></div>
</form>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    var api_key = '6969696969696969696969696969696';

    $(document).ready(function(){
      $.ajax({
        url: 'http://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=' + api_key + '&query=<?php echo $squery; ?>',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        jsonpCallback: 'testing'
      }).error(function() {
        console.log('error')
      }).done(function(response) {
          var i=0;
       // for (var i = 0; i < response.results.length; i++) {
          $('#search_results').append('<li>' + response.results[i].title + '</li>');
       // }
         $('#search_results_title').append(response.results[i].title);
         $('#search_results_release').append(response.results[i].release_date);
         $('#search_results_overview').append(response.results[i].overview);
         $('#search_results_poster').append('https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185' + response.results[i].poster_path);
         $('#search_results_votes').append(response.results[i].vote_count);
      });
    });
  </script>
```

**TOP FORM RESULTS**

Here is where the results are displayed from the form above **BUT**, I would like these results to be displayed as a value in the form below.

```
  <h3>Results</h3>

  <p id="error"></p>
  <ul id="search_results_title"></ul>
  <ul id="search_results_release"></ul>
  <ul id="search_results_overview"></ul>
  <ul id="search_results_poster"></ul>
  <ul id="search_results_votes"></ul>
```

**BOTTOM FORM DATA**

Here is the bottom form that **SHOULD** get submitted to the database with the "Results" that are above as the value.

```
    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="processmovie.php" method="get" enctype="text/plain">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="newMovieName" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Title</label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="newMovieName" name="movie_name" placeholder="Movie Title" required value="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="movieYear" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Year</label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="movieYear" name="movie_year" placeholder="Year" required>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="movieBio" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Storyline</label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
      <textarea type="email" class="form-control" id="movieBio" name="movie_bio" rows="4" placeholder="Enter Storyline" required></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="newImage" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Movie Cover URL</label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
      <input type="text" id="newImage" class="form-control" name="movie_img" placeholder="Enter URL" required>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="movieRating" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Rating</label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
      <select id="movieRating" name="movie_rating" class="form-control" required>
        <option value="G">G</option>
        <option value="PG">PG</option>
        <option value="PG-13">PG-13</option>
        <option value="R">R</option>
        <option value="NR">NR (Not Rated)</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-9">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Add Movie</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

I tried to use a variaty of code to try and get the value here is an example: `<?php echo $_GET['search_results_title'];?>`

I've also found examples like this: [How to pass the value of a form to another form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32241741/how-to-pass-the-value-of-a-form-to-another-form) but, my forms are on the same page and not different ones.

Comment: If the forms are in the same page, wouldn't it be the case to consider using Angular JS? All values flow on client side... even PHP isn't your issue (nor solution) here.

Comment: You are making an ajax call at time of loading the page and in that time there is not any value in `squery` variable. So, never the value got saved in `$squery` variable and you will never get proper data via Ajax call.

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to what you want. To me it looks like all you are asking for is to place your values from your ajax call into the second form. If that is the case then just use (in your `.done()` call) `$('#newMovieName').val(response.results[i].title);`, etc.. Am I not understanding you correctly?

Comment: @ioums correct... the top form works properly to display the results, the top form loads the page to itself but the results are displayed as `<ul id="search_results_title"></ul>` and I need it to be displayed as a "value" in the lower form after the page loads... could you provide an example/answer? that way if it works I can award you the "correct answer"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in my comment, you would just want to change your ajax call to something like this:

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'http://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=' + api_key + '&query=<?php echo $squery; ?>',
         dataType: 'jsonp',
         jsonpCallback: 'testing'
      }).error(function() {
         console.log('error')
      }).done(function(response) {
         var i=0;

         $('#newMovieName').val(response.results[i].title);
         $('#movieYear').val(response.results[i].release_date);
         $('#movieBio').val(response.results[i].overview);
         $('#newImage').val('https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185' + response.results[i].poster_path);
      });
```

(I'm not sure about the relationship you have between `response.results[i].vote_count` and `movieRating`)

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aLcf8a1L/) sort of showing the result, though I can't exactly replicate your code there because of the ajax calls

Comment: **awesome!** works like a charm... thanks for taking the time to help me out!